# AJAX response problem

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got this function:

```
function Ajax() {
    var xmlhttp, onready, open, response;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    this.onready = function(onready) {
        this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( this.xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && this.xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                onready.call();
            }
        }
    };

    this.open = function(_filename, _method) {
        this.xmlhttp.open(_method, _filename, true);
        this.xmlhttp.send(null);
    };

    this.response = function() {
        return this.xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
}


function rc() {
    var ajax = new Ajax();

    ajax.onready(function() {
        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = ajax.response();
    });

    ajax.open("ab.php","GET");
}

rc();
```

And the request is sent fine, but i can't extract the response.

- It shows that readyState doesn't exist in xmlhttp object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code I am getting "this.xmlhttp is undefined" for the line:

```
if ( this.xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && this.xmlhttp.status == 200)
```

You are already inside of the xmlhttp object. The line should be:

```
if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
```

This should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in Firebug, according to [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=35).

What version of firebug are you using?

Can you try

- Updating Firebug
- Trying the same with another browser? These days almost all browsers have a developer console.

Comment: I've restarted Firefox and i do not get this error now. However I still do not get the response.

Comment: @fgvjsfbjhoubb Are you sure the response is sent from the server? Did you try with any other browser?

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer shows white page like Firefox. What expected is response inside DIV with the id - comments. Firebug shows that i send the request to "ab.php" and i get the right response, but i can't "extract" it or pass it to the variable and then print it.